# How to get last line of multiline text with matching regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for hours now how to get last line of a multilines text.

[For example with :](https://jsfiddle.net/oo7h8059/)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante 
dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla  
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.
```

I would get :

```
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.
```

I tried with a regex like :

```
var y = x.match(/[\S]+$/);
```

But it returns :

```
null
```

How can I get last line of a multiline text with a regex in javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: Use [`x.trim().split("\n").pop()`](https://jsfiddle.net/qktvLfak/). Or `s.trim().match(/.*$/)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[\S]+$` (which is long for `\S+$`), means to matches all non-whitespace at the end of the string.

Since your string has a space at the end of the last line, it doesn't match anything.

Even if you removed that trailing space, it would only match `ipsum.`

Simply use: `.*$`

This relies on the fact that `.` doesn't match line-break characters by default *(`(?s)` can change that, when needed)*.

So it matches all characters from the last line-break until the end of the string.

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EqPTO4/2) for demo.

---

Now, if the text has one or more line-breaks after that last line, so it isn't really the *last* line, use `.*\s*$` instead. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqPTO4/3).

To not capture blank lines at the end, use a capture group to catch the last non-blank line: `(.*)\s*$`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqPTO4/4).

Answer (score 2):

I am not good with Regex.

However, to answer this, you can use `split('\n')`

```
var myText = <your multi line text>;
var lines = myText.split('\n');
console.log(lines[lines.length - 1]); // This should print last line
```

As per your JSFiddle, you have to take second last line as the last line is EMPTY

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
var y = x.split('\n');
alert(y[y.length - 2]);
```

Comment: Thank you!! How did you see the last line is empty ? I couldn't notice that.

Comment: As per your JSFiddle, </p> was in a  new line. So, after "imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum." also there was a \n character

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you can do this

```
var text = your text goes here;
var regex = /\n.*$/;
match = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match[0].slice(1));
```

Check for the match that starts with `\n` (newline character), and then ends with something else than `\n`, that will get you the last line. Finally just remove the first character from the match as it will be the starting `\n` (last character from the previous line).

Note that this will work only if the text is actually multiline - contains `\n` - so you should also test it to begin with.

```
if (text.indexOf('\n') == -1) return text;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `(.+)([^\s])` to ignore the last line if empty :

For multi paragraphs :

```js
var u = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
  var z = u[i].innerHTML.match(/(.+)([^\s])/g);
  console.log(z[z.length - 1]);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante 
dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla  
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. 
</p><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante 
dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla  
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. 
</p><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante 
dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla  
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. 
</p><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante 
dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla  
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. 
</p>
```

For single one :

```js
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
var y = x.match(/(.+)([^\s])/g);
console.log(y[y.length -1]);
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante     
dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla  
imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.   



                               </p>
```